# Winflash does not support this BIOS update ASUS windows 10 64 bit

Tags: windows, bios, flash

[image]

I tried to update my BIOS using EZ Flash 2 and the BIOS file `X553MAAS.215` via USB, but after rebooting the PC the BIOS file does not show. Does anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score -1):

i had the same issue
tried winflash it downloaded the 215 bios on its own but when i click on update it says not valid file

i contacted technical on support and pestered the live support guy
after a lot of pestering they have taken the 215 bios offline and now if u try to download it says 404 no file

i think they have realised that the bios file is not valid and will be updating itwith a new valid file that will show in easy flash

fingers crossed